# javascript file not working in a plugin template file

Tags: customization, javascript, child-theme

Hello and thank you for taking time out of your day to help me.

I am working on a website and I want to make minor changes to how a form is displayed. I am using a child theme, I have copied the template file to the appropriate location of the theme and I have enqueued the javascript file that will contain my script. I can see that the file is working because currently, I am adding borders to all divs.

My problem however is that the file I am trying to customize is a template file of the plugin Dokan and pops up on the push of a button and when the pop up appears the javascript file doesn’t have any effect on the elements within the pop up(see the pictures below).

[image]

[image]

hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Best regards

Comment: Hello Daxi, welcome to the WordPress Development community! Your question seems like it might require specific knowledge about Dokan in order to answer, which might make it [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for our stack. That said, it also might be that your JavaScript simply does not account for elements created after it is executed - in which case it would be a question about generic HTML/JS (which are also off-topic D:). You might want to look into DOM's `MutationObserver`, or jQuery's `.on()` perhaps, or investigate the Dokan code for events you might leverage

Comment: Okay, I understand, thanks for the reply.